# Using JEditorPane and its setPage method

Tags: java, user-interface, jeditorpane

I have an editor pane which displays an HTML file. When I ask it to do it once, it displays the HTML file fine. I then make changes to my HTML file and use the `setPage` method so that it prints the updated HTML file but it doesn't do this even though the HTML file is changed.

Is this a problem with the Editor pane or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the [JavaDoc for `setPage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage(java.net.URL)), I see the following:

> If the desired URL is the one currently being displayed, the document will not be
>   reloaded. To force a document reload it is necessary to clear the stream description
>   property of the document. The following code shows how this can be done:
>
> ```
> Document doc = jEditorPane.getDocument();
> doc.putProperty(Document.StreamDescriptionProperty, null);
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much, I have been looking for a way to get `JEditorPane` to do this for a while now. Guess I should read the docs more!

Answer (score 0):

I've done some tests and I've reproduced this behaviour. When I am calling setPage and passing as argument the same URL that was passed previously in the same method, the JEditorPane seems to ignore the call.

A simple work around: test if the new Url is the same as the previous one. If yes, format the Url a bit differently. For example add an %20 at the end. The new Url actually refers to the same page, but the JEditorPane will consider it as a new one and it will properly reload it.